# Assigning to fields in array property in delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a class which stores generic items in an array. These items are accessed by a default array property:

```
TMyList<TData> = class
private
  items: array of TItem<TData>;
public
  function get(position: integer): TData;
  procedure edit(position: integer; data: TData);
  property Values[position: integer]: TData read get write edit; default;
end;

implementation
function TMyList<TData>.get(position: integer): TData;
begin
result:= items[position];
end;

procedure TMyList<TData>.edit(position: integer; data: TData);
var
  item: TItem<TData>;
begin
  items[position]:= item;
end;
end;
```

In this case the items I am storing are all of the type TTest which also has its own properties:

```
TTest = record
  private
      FTest: string;
      procedure setFTest(const Value: string);
  public
    property Test: string read FTest write setFTest;
end;

implementation
procedure TColouredPoint.setFTest(const Value: String);
begin
  FTest:= Value;
end;
end;
```

I want to be able to change the value of FTest for an instance of TTest like this:

```
var
  points: TMyList<TTest>;
...
points[index].Test:= 'test';
```

but this doesn't do anything. There is no error message but the value of points[index].Test doesn't change.

Instead I have to do this:

```
var
  points: TMyList<TTest>;
  temp: TTest;
...
temp:= points[index];
temp.Test:= 'test';
points[index]:= temp;
```

Why does the first version not work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why does the first version not work?

Consider this code

```
points[index].Test := 'test';
```

The indexed property is converted by the compiler into the a function call and so the compiler effectively compiles this:

```
points.get(index).Text := 'test';
```

Now, `points.get(index)` returns a copy of the `TTest` value. Since you don't assign that to anything, the compiler introduces a local variable to hold the return value.

So your code becomes, in effect:

```
var
  tmp: TTest;
...
tmp := points.get(index);
tmp.Text := 'test';
```

That's the last thing that is ever done with `tmp`, and so the modifications that you make to `tmp.Text` are simply discarded leaving the underlying object untouched.

---

This issue is pretty hard to get around when working with value types.

The generic Delphi `TList<T>` collection allows you direct access to the underlying array, which allows you to operate on the stored values directly.

Another approach is to use a reference rather than a value. One simple way to achieve that is to use a `T` that is a class rather than a record, i.e. a reference type rather than a value type.

Answer (score 3):

It is because `TTest` is a `record`. The getter of the list returns a copy of the actual record and that is what you are changing. It should work when you declare `TTest` as a `class`, but then you have to take care of creating and destroying it.